# Visual Studio Installer Project and Content / Config File Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, dependencies, setup-project

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 that has a DLL, Windows Service, and a Visual Studio setup project. The DLL has an app.config file.

```
SLN
 |
 |--DLL
 |   |--Email Templates
 |   |--app.config
 |
 |--Service (depends on DLL)
 |
 |--Setup Project (includes service)
```

The idea is that the service calls the DLL which monitors things on a timer and sends emails. I'm running into problems with dependency tracking though.

Every necessary piece doesn't make it to the final Setup project. When I say that the service depends on the DLL, I expect it to copy everything in the project output for the DLL, including the email templates and the app.config. Instead I just get the DLL file itself. I got around the email templates by adding them to My.Resources but all the settings for the DLL are in the app.config for the DLL and Visual Studio is not including it in the project output for the service, even though the service is marked as depending on the DLL.

What's the right way to get Visual Studio to understand that the dependency is not just on the DLL, but that it needs to include the app.config and content files also?

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of got it working. Using the app.config (my.settings) didn't work. The installer project wouldn't carry it through. However, I could add the content files from the DLL. In the setup project, in addition to adding the primary output, select the content files (right click on setup > add > project output > select DLL > select content files). So with that, I was able to get the email templates to flow through without using my.resources. I then went with an XML config file and marked that as content and it made its way into the installer.